# laravel salesforce require_once?

Tags: php, laravel, salesforce, soql

I got a problem.I made a new class for my controller, in this class I do that to connect to salesforce

```
require_once ('salesforce/soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
```

but I still have a problem.

> (1/1) FatalErrorException Class 'App\Services\SforceEnterpriseClient'
>   not found

Comment: I suggest using Laravel's service container to register new classes, see docs here - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container

Comment: give `namespace App\Services` namespace to your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel is not meant to use require_once, which is a standard PHP expression. Use a Composer package such as this: https://packagist.org/packages/phpforce/soap-client

If you do need to require a specific file, add it into your app directory, maybe under a new Integrations folder and give it a believe namespace of `App\Integrations`. Then, in your controller, `use App\Integrations\SforceEnterpriseClient;`

Comment: i just need to upload this package ?

Comment: I have never used this package, but hundreds of thousands of others have, so that's a good sign. Use Composer to pull in the package and then you can use it as I mentioned above. I do not know if the files are the same- that is up to you to check- but I would think that it would suffice for your needs. If it doesn't, still use your file, but use a namespace instead of require_once.

Comment: @AlexisCapdepon, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer. Glad I could help!